Load python data similar to json.loads
I'm wondering if there's a way to import Python data, e.g
[{'test1': True, 'test2': [0, 1, 2], 'test3': None}]

I need to produce a large Python data dump, e.g 300MB. First thought is to import the data as a module, so I tried to add a heading and a trailing,
# heading, new newline here, it assigns the list to variable "a"
import json
a = 

# trailing
with open('json-dump', 'w') as f:
    for row in a:
        f.write(json.dumps(row) + '\n')

But it would take tons of memory to do that, I created a 8GB swap and it results in OOM, and Python is killed.
Is there any better way to do that?

When exactly do you get OOM and what are you trying to optimize - export or import? It's unclear from the question.

@wombatonfire I need a correct way to do that, or a solution that needs less memory. In short, there's nothing I can do other than adding swaps, and I think it's not the right way to solve this.

Well, "a solution that needs less memory" is basically not to put in memory everything you're trying to put there. Unfortunately, it's impossible to tell from your question where that problem happens. From your example it looks like the data you're "exporting" is already in memory. This question needs to be improved.

I don't understand what you try to do. In title you have json.loads but in question you use json.dumps. You say you have large data e.g 300MB but it is not so much. Writing data to file shouldn't makes problem. Problem can be if you first have to read all data to memory. But I don't know what data you have in memory. Maybe you can get them partially - and this should use less memory.

@furas Yes, the problems is to unserialize such data requires lots of memory, and do you think is there a way to do that?

@daisy It will require lots of memory only if you try to load an entire dataset to memory. You don't have to. You can read and deserialize records one by one or in batches. Text files can be iterated line by line, binary files can be accessed in chunks of a specific size using offsets.

@wombatonfire are you aware of any library can do that for Python dumps?

You don't need a special library for that. If the data you need to load is in a json format in a text file, with one record on each line, you simply iterate over the lines of this file in loop, deserializing (loads()) each line individually.
